# I have some errors in Webapplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I'm trying to build a website, which is based on ASP.net. I had a login page and I already have some users in the database. but when I type in the right username and password, the system shows me a error, which said:"/"Application server error, cannot find the resources.
I'm thinks is there any problems with my web.congif? or any other problems. I do need help.

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=databaseurl; pwd=password;uid=username; database=databasename"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
      <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Register/Login.aspx" timeout="2800"/>
      </authentication>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Thanks

Jimmy

Comment: Can you please describe more about the error? Example: Which link you access, which aspx code, the login action.
From my guess looks like after login you are trying to redirect to a page, which is not exists.

Answer (score 0):

You did not give enough information, so I'll take a swing.

In Visual Studio 2010, if you set a page as `Start Page` and delete that page accidently, you'll receive `The resource cannot be found.` error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can I fix this problem? How can I give the path without using PostbackURL?

Comment: Right click on an `aspx` page, and then click `Set As Start Page`